# CSS element rotation, parts cut off?

Tags: css, image-rotation, css-transforms

See this image:

http://i56.tinypic.com/311vw51.png

You will note that part of the border of image 2 and 3 (left side) are cut off, not entirely visible. I'm using the transform:rotate(xdeg); CSS rule.

Is there anything that can be done about this apart from adding more padding or what not? I tried changing the z-index but that didn't seem to help? Am I missing something?

Comment: picture link is broken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have an `overflow: hidden` on the parent element? It's likely that your rotated elements are overstepping the boundaries of the ancestor elements, of which one has an `overflow: hidden` set on it. Removing that should stop the elements from being clipped.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your markup and part of the CSS?

By the way, looking at the picture you posted, it could be that one of the parent elements has the `overflow` property set to `hidden`.